# Modifying Content in JavaScript-Generated HTML Code

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to modify the innerHTML of a div when clicked. I have dynamically generated an array of divs, and I want to specifically access the table which the user has clicked.

I have tried dynamically setting the ID of the tables in the JavaScript code:

```
(for var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
  var IDvalue = "foo";
  // append table to HTML string.
  html += "<div onclick='modifyInnerHTML(\"" + IDvalue + "\")'>...</div>";
  var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  divs[divs.length-1].id=array[i].IDvalue;
}
```

Then in `modifyInnerHTML()` I access the element by ID:

```
function modifyInnerHTML(id){
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML+="Add an update";
}
```

While I think this code should work fine, it is breaking at the `document.getElementById(id)` function, and I realize the id of the divs is not being set dynamically.  Any thoughts on why this might be or are there faster ways to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by `divs[divs.length-1].id=array[i].IDvalue;` This seems wrong to me.

Comment: Could you please describe more precisely the end result you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to change the innerHTML of the div the user clicks - fairly simple :)

Comment: @addy2012 That's for assigning the IDvalue to the last div in the document

Comment: @wagtail yes, but i did not know that the `array[i].IDvalue` syntax works.

Comment: @addy2012 So define var = array[i], then var.IDvalue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better use a DOM manipulation library for this, like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

As for the events, jQuery will let you define them in a much more reliable way. You should avoid defining event handlers in attributes anyway, better attach them to the DOM using references to elements, or, better yet, jQuery elemnt sets.

---

Case 1: Generate some `divs` dynamically with an event handler already set:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    $("<div>")
        .addClass("clickable-div")
        .html("click me!")
        .on("click", function() {
            $(this).html("You clicked me!");
        })
        .appendTo("body");
}
```

Case 2: Add an event handler to all `div`s that contain the class `clickable-div`

```
$("div.clickable-div").on("click", function() {
    $(this).html("You clicked me!");
});
```

jQuery is **much** faster to get things done with than anything you'd write in pure JS.

Comment: OK, is there any faster way to use jQuery than what I've used (or tried to use) in JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, I'll try to figure out what you really wanted to do here and translate it to jQuery.

Comment: Nice, I think I have seen this before!  I'll implement it!!

Comment: Take the time to read the docs thouroughly. It will save you massive amounts of time later on.